# Can't POST (and parse) params to app.post() in express.js

Tags: node.js, post, express

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js) but for some reasons the solution given is not working for me. In my express.js I have:

```
...

bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
...
```

Run test using POSTman

[image]

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body) // undefined
   console.log(req.params) // undefined
})
```

and the result:

[image]

So both body & params are empty. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the solution in the link you provided doesn't work is because that version of `body-parser` is out of date and doesn't include `form-data` parsing anymore (and it used to be bundled with express).

With that being said, based on your screenshot, it looks like you are sending data of type `multipart/form-data`(you can check this in the request headers) to your server and your code sample only shows middleware that handles `urlencoded` and `json` data types.

You need to add middleware that handles that data type.  The latest body parser says (https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> - [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy#readme)
> - [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme)
> - [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)
> - [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

So check out one of the above parsers.  I use `busboy` and it works great.